# How to duplicate rows of self-referenced table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, hierarchical-data, self-reference

Suppose we have a self-referenced table like this

```
CREATE TABLE Month
(
  Id int IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
  Title char(128)
)
CREATE TABLE Entity
(
 Id int IDENTITY(1,1)  PRIMARY KEY,
 MonthId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Month(Id),
 Name char(128),
 ParentId int FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Entity(Id),
)
```

I want to copy all rows of a certain MonthId to another MonthId. The duplicate parentId's should be updated as well, the entities and their parents should be in the same month.

as an example assume we have

```
Id        MonthId    Name     ParentId
------------------------------------
1         1          name1     null
2         1          name11    1
3         1          name3     null 
4         1          name31    3
5         1          name311   4
```

after copying monthId=1 rows to monthId=2 the result should be like this:

```
Id        MonthId    Name     ParentId
------------------------------------
1         1          name1     null
2         1          name11    1
3         1          name3     null 
4         1          name31    3
5         1          name311   4
newId1    2          name1     null
newId2    2          name11    newId1
newId3    2          name3     null 
newId4    2          name31    newId3
newId5    2          name311   newId4
```

The newId's are the values that generated by the DBMS.

Note: I use Sql-Server 2012 as DBMS.

Comment: Side note: *please* don't use `char(128)` for your `name` column! This will make **all** your names be 128 characters long - shorter ones padded with spaces up to the defined length! This is horribly bad, waste of space - use `varchar(128)` instead which uses only as much space as needed

Comment: Its just for the example, I use nvarchar(128) in the real application, as i need Unicode characters.

Comment: I can think of a somewhat cumbersome way of inserting records to a temporary table with the old ids and old parent ids, and then insert them to the main table with the correct values, but I'm sure it can be done in a more straight forward way, so I'm not going to post this as an answer.

Comment: A. Are you sure your  table definition is legal (Specifically, `Month(Id)
`)? If so, are you only concerned with the `ParentId` column?

Comment: @Amit, I corrected the schema definition. The main part is the parentId.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works fine without any assumptions:

```
DECLARE @baseMonthId int = 1
DECLARE @newMonthId int = 2

DECLARE @newRows TABLE(id int, orig_id int)

MERGE INTO Entity
USING (
  SELECT Id, Name, ParentId FROM Entity WHERE MonthId = @baseMonthId
) AS cf
ON 1 = 0
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT(MonthId, Name, ParentId) Values(@newMonthId, cf.Name, cf.ParentId)
OUTPUT inserted.Id, cf.Id INTO @newRows(id, orig_id);

UPDATE Entity
SET Parentid = 
  ( 
    SELECT 
      nr.id
    FROM @newRows nr
      WHERE nr.orig_id = Entity.ParentId
   )
WHERE MonthId = @newMonthId;
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If we can rely on `Entity.Name` being unique for a given `Entity.MonthId`, then it can be done in 2 SQL statements:

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/db97a/2)

```
-- copy records, but don't set the ParentId yet.
INSERT INTO Entity (MonthId, Name, ParentId)
SELECT 2, Name, null
FROM Entity
WHERE MonthId = 1;

-- set the ParentId in the 2nd step.
UPDATE e
SET e.ParentId = (
  SELECT parentNew.Id
  FROM Entity innerOld
  JOIN Entity parentOld
    ON parentOld.Id = innerOld.ParentId
  JOIN Entity parentNew
    ON parentNew.MonthId = e.MonthId
   AND parentNew.Name = parentOld.Name
  WHERE innerOld.MonthId = 1
    AND innerOld.Name = e.Name
)
FROM Entity e
WHERE e.MonthId = 2;
```

One advantage of this approach is that it doesn't make any assumptions about how the `Id` values are generated.